# Change URL domain name website Prestashop

Tags: url, url-rewriting, xampp, prestashop

I want to move my PrestaShop website from the FTP client to my local machine for testing purposes. However, all the links of the moved website stay unchanged with the domain name site.com instead of site.dev.

Is there any way to replace the old domain name by the new one that I've specified in the host file? I mean having site.dev/index.php instead of site.com/index.php.

Is a such thing possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the back office Preferences -> SEO & Urls -> under Shop domain name option You can change it to Your development domain name.

Comment: @marouane91 Prestashop would let You access directly backoffice by default using address like http://site.dev/admin***. Try to turn off URL rewriting that You mentioned upwards.

Comment: OMG i've just retried what you've told me, turned off and back on the URL rewriting (URL Simplifying) and it magicly worked, how is that even possible all i did is turn back to the original state ?? A Thousands thanks to you ElectroNis :D but still wondering what caused this so i could deal with it in the futur if i ever face it ^^

Comment: That's because of the .htaccess's regeneration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to edit all page then use editor to replace all occurrence in all file of site.com=>site.dev. This you can to by one step using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.6.8.html) editor.

In Notepad++ you can open all file at once by select all(Ctrl+A) then RightClick -> Edit in Notepad++. Then Edit Menu->Replace, type both string->Replace in all open documents.

---

If you cant/don't want to edit all pages then there is only one option, for that you need to active site.com as well as: In site.com use URL rewrite to redirect all request to site.com . If you can tell me the hosting server then I can tell you proper URL rewrite method.

for ex.

`RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule (.)* http://site.dev/$1 [NC,L]`

on Apache in .htaccess file